# Reporting tab is not visible in TFS admin console

Tags: tfs, reporting

We have installed TFS 2015 and SQL server 2014 Developer Edition.

From SQL we have enabled SSRS native and SSAS and Management tool as well.

Could you please help me how we can populate Reporting Tab in admin console

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add reporting in two places: to TFS itself, and then to your team project collection:

1. Open the administration console for TFS and go to the **Reporting** node to start the configuration process.

[image]

2. Select the **Use Reporting** check box. On the **Warehouse** tab, provide the name of the report server and instance for the warehouse database. Use the default name for the database (TFS_Warehouse), and test the connection.

[image]

3. Provide the same server and instance information for **Analysis Services**, but use the default name for the analysis database (TFS_Analysis). Provide an account name and password for a data sources account, a special account you've created just for this purpose as described in [Service accounts and dependencies in TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/service-accounts-dependencies-tfs?view=tfs-2018).

[image]

4. For **Reports**, provide the server name and the instance name in **Server**, separated by a slash.

Use **Populate URLs** to automatically populate the next two boxes. Add the same data sources account information you provided on the previous tab.

[image]

Once you finish, databases will be created, and the warehouse will start building.

[image]

5. Add the report server to the team project collection. Edit the information in **Reports Folder**.

[image]

Detailed steps you can refer to the article below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/admin/add-a-report-server?view=tfs-2018